# Is Objective-C an Interpreted or Compiled language?

Tags: programming-languages, objective-c, compiler, interpreters

I want to know if Objective-C is an interpreted or a compiled language.

Comment: I always thought it was a compiled language. I'm curious where the confusion comes from...

Comment: @Mako: Please explain where you saw that objective-C was interpreted.  Please provide the quote or the link that confused you.

Comment: Nitpicking: Interpreted/compiled is a property of the language implementation, not of the language (although with most languages most implementations fall into one category). And even then it's blurry - if you go by the strict, and correct, definition of compilation, even most dynamic/"scripting" languages are compiled - to bytecode, but still compiled.

Comment: Languages are *specifications*, often in some *document* written in English (but some languages have formalized their semantics in more mathematical notations). Being interpreted or compiled is a property of *implementations*, not of *languages*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is neither. Objective-C is a programming language. A programming language is an abstract concept. A programming language is a set of mathematical rules and definitions. Programming languages aren't compiled or interpreted, they just *are*.

Compilation and interpretation aren't properties of a programming language, they are properties of, well, a compiler or an interpreter (duh). *Every* language can be implemented by a compiler and an interpreter, and *most* languages have both compiled and interpreted implementations. In fact, the majority of modern language implementations utilize *both* an interpreter *and* a compiler in the *same* execution engine for maximum performance.

For Objective-C specifically, I know of three implementations: gobjc, clang and oscompiler, but a quick Google search turned up two more. Of those five implementations, three are compilers and two are interpreters.

Comment: great explanation thank you; one question what was your search query for google?

Comment: Part of the question the OP is asking stems from the fact that Objective-C was originally run through a pre-processor (and not directly run through an interpreted or a compiler) which  generated C code. This could then be either run through a compiler that generates native machine code, or interpreted in some form (aside: I built a C interpreter once, just for fun). For simplicities sake people do say "C is a compiled language" - which - though wrong - actually denotes that C *usually* runs through a compiler.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you mind linking me to an objective-c interpreter as I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: So while C can obviously be interpreted, I think it is safe to say that the rationale behind the language is to allow for efficient compilation, yielding a run-time performance close to what you can obtain with assembler. Hence, interpreting C is possible (and even useful in some situations), but it is counter to the original intentions of the language's designers.

Comment: @Monolo: JRuby+Truffle can (experimentally) use a C interpreter called TruffleC to interpret Ruby C extensions at runtime, instead of linking against natively compiled libraries. This, interestingly, results in *better* performance than using compiled C extensions from YARV (the "standard" Ruby implementation). Let me repeat that: using *interpreted* C extensions from JRuby is faster than using *compiled* C extensions from YARV: http://chrisseaton.com/rubytruffle/cext/ http://chrisseaton.com/rubytruffle/modularity15/rubyextensions.pdf

Comment: The Objective-C language defers as many decisions as it can from compile time and link time to runtime. Whenever possible, it does things dynamically. **This means that the language requires not just a compiler, but also a runtime system to execute the compiled code**. The runtime system acts as a kind of operating system for the Objective-C language; it’s what makes the language work.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler):

> Some language specifications spell out that implementations must
>   include a compilation facility; for example, Common Lisp. However,
>   there is nothing inherent in the definition of Common Lisp that stops
>   it from being interpreted. Other languages have features that are very
>   easy to implement in an interpreter, but make writing a compiler much
>   harder; for example, APL, SNOBOL4, and many scripting languages allow
>   programs to construct arbitrary source code at runtime with regular
>   string operations, and then execute that code by passing it to a
>   special evaluation function. To implement these features in a compiled
>   language, programs must usually be shipped with a runtime library that
>   includes a version of the compiler itself.

I think clange (the main objec compiler) ship with a runtime library to achieve the dynamic nature of the objective-c the language.